# pymysql.err.programmingError: (1064)

Tags: python, sql, xampp, pymysql

I'm stuck with storing blob into xampp server. This is the error that I'm getting.

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '5\\xd2\\xe0\\xe5yllN\\xbc\\xa7!\\x11!\\x16\\xcftaJ\\xd1\\x863\\xbf\\x9a\\x9aF\\x83\\xe8\\xc9\\...' at line 2")
```

This is the function that is supposed to save the blob into xampp. Data type is set to mediumblob in xampp. I'm using tkinter and this function is bound to a button.

```py
def save_to_db():
    get_id_no = id_no_var.get()
    get_first_name = first_name_var.get()
    get_middle_name = middle_name_var.get()
    get_last_name = last_name_var.get()
    get_course = course_var.get()
    raw_qr_code_id = str(get_id_no + get_first_name + get_middle_name + get_last_name + get_course)
    final_qr_code_id = str(raw_qr_code_id.replace(" ", ""))
    filename = (final_qr_code_id + ".png")

    raw_image = (filename)
    image = open(raw_image, 'rb')
    image_binary = image.read()

    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `student_information` (`id_no`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `course`, `qr_code_id`, `qr_code_blob`)
                VALUES  ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')""" % (get_id_no, get_first_name, get_middle_name, get_last_name, get_course, final_qr_code_id, image_binary))
    connect_db.commit()
```

Comment: What do your different functions return? a good first way to debug would be to store your query in a variable then print it before executing it with `cursor.execute`

Comment: Sorry for not putting everything in context. I'm using tkinter, and this function is bound to a button. The idea is to save all entries including the blob into the xampp server by simply clicking the button. Everything seems to working fine, except for the BLOB error. If I take that blob off of the function, everything writes fine into the server. Sorry for the sloppy code structure, i'm new to programming.

Comment: is your field (qr_code_blob) defined as BLOB? can you try `cursor.execute` with a `,` instead of the `%` between the query string and the values tuple

Comment: The qr code is in a form of a PNG file. I'm trying to store the PNG file as a BLOB into xampp.

Comment: Still getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to insert the data:
I first created a table (Used LONGBLOB type because of the size of my picture):

```sql
MariaDB [DB]> create table TEST ( id int, file_file LONGBLOB);
```

Then binarised a picture

```py
image = open('/home/med/Pictures/Screenshot from 2019-12-19 12-48-53.png', 'rb')
image_binary = image.read()
```

After that I used the following query (notice single quotes around the query and double around the `%s`)

```py
connection.execute('''INSERT INTO TEST (`id`, `file_file`) VALUES ("%s", "%s")''', (1, image_binary))
# <sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.LegacyCursorResult at 0x7f2b24165580>
```

Checking if injection worked

```sql
MariaDB [DB]> select count(*) from TEST;                      
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [DB]>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have finally found the problem. It has something to do with the combination of """INSERT INTO.....""" along with '%s' and the % after that. Still a little hazy as to why this is the case. Apparently, strings behave differently when stored using "..." and """...""" Will delve deeper into this once i'm finished. I'm just glad this bug is fixed. Thanks!